# creating a timezone aware datetime object returns a wrong timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

when I create a timezone aware datetime object for `'US/Eastern'` and print it out, It shows as if my time zone is `-4:56` instead of `-4:00`

```
>>> obj = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 9, 30, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
>>> print(obj)
2020-07-01 09:30:00-04:56
```

instead of the expected:

```
2020-07-01 09:30:00-04:00
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: the "localize trap" is an old problem of `pytz`, you can find more info [here](https://blog.ganssle.io/tag/dateutil.html) on *why* it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mentioned in the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) that constructing datetime objects doesn't work this way.

You are supposed to do this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from pytz import timezone

eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
obj = eastern.localize(datetime(2020, 7, 1, 9, 30))
```

```
>>> obj
datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 9, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
>>> print(obj)
2020-07-01 09:30:00-04:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) - you can safely construct the tz-aware datetime object using your originally intended method:

```
import datetime
import dateutil

obj = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1, 9, 30, tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Eastern'))
print(obj)
# 2020-07-01 09:30:00-04:00
```

In Python 3.9, there will be [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html) as part of the standard lib for that task.