# Unexpected timezone offset when manually constructing a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am manually constructing a datetime object in Python:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(
...             2020, 4, 3, 12, 0, 0,
...             tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
...         )
>>> str(dt)
'2020-04-03 12:00:00-05:51'
>>>
```

On the other hand:

```
>>> naive = datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 12, 0, 0,)
>>> pytz.timezone('America/Chicago').localize(naive)
datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 12, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Chicago' CDT-1 day, 19:00:00 DST>)
>>> dt = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago').localize(naive)
>>> str(dt)
'2020-04-03 12:00:00-05:00'
>>>
```

Why is the timezone offset "-05:51" in the first code snippet and "-05:00" in the second. Since Daylight Saving Time is active in America/Chicago on Apr 3, 2020, they should both show "-05:00".

Comment: Have a look at `dateutil`, you could avoid the "localize issue" there. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62578255/10197418) for an example  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can localize a datetime using the following code:

```
dt = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago').localize(datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 12, 0, 0))
str(dt)
```

The output is:

```
'2020-04-03 12:00:00-05:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the right way to do what I want. MrFuppes also gave a link explaining why my original way doesn't work.