# How should I print the time in a specific timezone in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

This question is really quite simple, and it's basically the title. I am in Western Australia.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python)

Comment: Specifically, use the datetime and pytz module. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28576383/12279039)

Comment: Save yourself some headache and use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of pytz - e.g. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62578255/10197418).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup the pytz and datetime module is the way to go:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

timezone = 'Australia/Perth'
py_timezone = pytz.timezone(timezone)
current_datetime = datetime.now(py_timezone)
```

If you need to find a specific timezone you use the `all_timezones` property in pytz, which will return a list of all timezones.

```
import pytz
all_timezones = pytz.all_timezones
```

Comment: `datetime.now(py_timezone)` - getting a timezone-aware datetime object with `pytz` works for `.now()`, however, the generic way to do this would be `py_timezone.localize(naive_dtobj)`. IMHO, localize (and normalize) should always be mentioned in the context of `pytz` since I've seen many cases where this went wrong (some of my own code included).

Answer (score 1):

`pytz` is [likely to be deprecated](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-615-support-for-the-iana-time-zone-database-in-the-standard-library/3468/16) in the future.

The newer and better way to do this, as of Python 3.9 (currently in beta) is to use the [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html) module.

Current time in Amsterdam:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

now = datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo("Europe/Amsterdam"))
```

Convert a time in one timezone to another:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

dt = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 12, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh"))
converted_dt = dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo("Africa/Windhoek"))
```

Get available timezones:

```py
import zoneinfo

zoneinfo.available_timezones()
```

You can use this already in Python 3.6+ with the [`backports.zoneinfo` package](https://pypi.org/project/backports.zoneinfo/).

Comment: You can use `backports` to use zoneinfo already in earlier versions of Python

Comment: Good point, I've added that into the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

important to notice is also that if you only want to have the *local* time, i.e. according to the timezone setting of your OS, you only need `datetime`.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
# print(now)
# 2020-06-27 13:08:12.007814
```

`now` would be a naive datetime object, i.e. it does not know about the timezone. Python will by default assume that it belongs in your local timezone (not e.g. UTC).

You can even make it timezone-aware without any other imports:

```
now = now.astimezone()
# print(now)
# 2020-06-27 13:08:12.007814+02:00 # I'm on CEST at the moment; UTC+2
```

---

If you want to implement different timezones or change timezones, here's an example how to do it with `dateutil`:

```
import dateutil
awst = dateutil.tz.gettz('Australia/Perth')
now_naive = datetime.now()
now_aware = now_naive.replace(tzinfo=awst)

print(now_aware.strftime('%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z'))
# Sat 27 Jun 2020 17:08:53 +0800 AWST

# same time in another timezone:
cest = dateutil.tz.gettz('Europe/Berlin')
now_aware = now_aware.astimezone(cest)

print(now_aware.strftime('%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z'))
# Sat 27 Jun 2020 11:08:53 +0200 CEST
```

For Python 3.9 `zoneinfo`, the methods are basically the same so changing from dateutil to zoneinfo is feasable.